# How to correctly update a MongoDB timeseries array without duplicates?

Tags: python, mongodb, time-series, pymongo

I have the following timeseries array (named "data"), nested in a mongodb document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a235e645bb1000704593960"), 
"data" : [
    {
       "Volume" : NumberLong(41527200), 
       "Adj Close" : 171.850006, 
       "High" : 172.139999, 
       "Low" : 168.440002, 
       "Date" : ISODate("2017-11-30T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
       "Close" : 171.850006, 
       "Open" : 170.429993
    }, 
    {
        "Volume" : NumberLong(39726100), 
        "Adj Close" : 171.050003, 
        "High" : 171.669998, 
        "Low" : 168.5, 
        "Date" : ISODate("2017-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "Close" : 171.050003, 
        "Open" : 169.949997
    }, 
    {
        "Volume" : NumberLong(39759300), 
        "Adj Close" : 171.050003, 
        "High" : 171.669998, 
        "Low" : 168.5, 
        "Date" : ISODate("2017-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "Close" : 171.050003, 
            "Open" : 169.949997
        }, 

    ], 
    "ticker" : "AAPL", 
    "last_update" : ISODate("2017-12-07T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

My issue is that when I update the timeseries, some array elements for a given date may change. For example, in the array there are 2 records for 2017-12-01. All fields are the same except "Volume." When I update the array however, a new record is added to the array, instead of updating the existing 2017-01-01 record.

I am currently updating the document with the following:

```
self.__db.equity_data.update({'ticker': ticker,
                              'last_update': {'$lt': record['last_update']}},
                             {'$set': {'last_update':record['last_update']},
                              '$addToSet': {'data': {'$each': record['data']}}}, 
                               upsert=True
                                 )
```

Is there any way that I can ensure that a duplicate item (based on the date) is not added to the array, and instead update the existing array element?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with pymongo, but have you tried setting `upsert` flag to `false`? It should prevent creating new documents instead of updating the old ones if the rest of the statements is correct. Also, you should try adding the `multi` flag because the above code will only update one document by default. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe upsert applies to the document level. This is at the array level. I might be wrong though. I tried upsert = False but this did not produce the desired result.